# TortoiseSVN Slow Diff

Tags: windows-10, tortoisesvn, diff

I've been using TortoiseSVN for a few years now and whenever I've done a "Diff" on a file, generally the result comes up in only a second or two.

Recently Windows 10 did an update as well as I updated to TortoiseSVN 1.9.7. Now when I do a "Diff" on a file it takes close to a minute to display the results.

If I do an "svn diff" from the command line however the results are displayed to the terminal almost immediately so it would appear there is something wrong with the way TortoiseMerge displays the results.

I saw another post suggest to try `svn cleanup`, which I tried, but did not help in my case.

If anyone has any suggestions, then I would appreciate the help.